# When is padding for shared memory really required?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am confused by 2 documents from NVidia. [CUDA Best Practices](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#shared-memory-and-memory-banks) describes that shared memory is organized in banks, and in general in 32-bit mode each 4 bytes is a bank (that is how I understood it). However [Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) goes into details how padding should be added to scan algorithm because of bank conflicts.

The problem for me is, the basic type for this algorithm as presented is `float` and its size is 4 bytes. Thus each `float` is a bank and there is no bank conflict.

So is my understanding correct -- i.e. if you work on `4*N`-byte types you don't have to worry about bank conflicts because by definition there will be none? If no, how should I understand it (when to use padding)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might be interested in [this webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/sharedmemoryusage_july2011.mp4) from the [NVIDIA CUDA webinar page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars)  Shared memory including banks are described also on slides 35-45 from [this webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Memory_Optimization.pdf).

In general shared memory bank conflicts can occur any time two different threads are attempting to access (from the same kernel instruction) locations within shared memory for which the lower 4 (pre-cc2.0 devices) or 5 bits (cc2.0 and newer devices) of the address are the same. When a bank conflict does occur, the shared memory system serializes accesses to locations that are in the same bank, thus reducing performance. Padding attempts to avoid this for some access patterns.  Note that for cc2.0 and newer, if all the bits are the same (i.e. same location) this does not cause a bank conflict.

Pictorially, we can look at it like this:

```
__shared__ int A[2048];
int my;
my = A[0]; // A[0] is in bank 0
my = A[1]; // A[1] is in bank 1
my = A[2]; // A[2] is in bank 2
...
my = A[31]; // A[31] is in bank 31 (cc2.0 or newer device)
my = A[32]; // A[32] is in bank 0
my = A[33]; // A[33] is in bank 1
```

now, if we access shared memory across threads in a warp, we may hit bank conflicts:

```
my = A[threadIdx.x];    // no bank conflicts or serialization - handled in one trans.
my = A[threadIdx.x*2];  // 2-way bank conflicts - will cause 2 level serialization
my = A[threadIdx.x*32]; // 32-way bank conflicts - will cause 32 level serialization
```

Let's take a closer look at the 2-way bank conflict above.  Since we are multiplying `threadIdx.x`  by 2, thread 0 accesses location 0 in bank 0 but thread 16 accesses location 32 which is *also* in bank 0, thus creating a bank conflict.  For the 32-way example above, all the addresses correspond to bank 0.  Thus 32 transactions to shared memory must occur to satisfy this request, as they are all serialized.

So to answer the question, *if* I knew that my access patterns would be like this for example:

```
my = A[threadIdx.x*32];
```

Then I might want pad my data storage so that `A[32]` is a dummy/pad location, as is `A[64]`, `A[96]`  etc.
Then I could fetch the same data like this:

```
my = A[threadIdx.x*33];
```

And get my data with no bank conflicts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, again :-) you rescued my understanding!

Comment: Hi Robert, I've read on a CUDA book that in Kepler devices, you must calculate how many padding elements are needed. Is there any relation with double precision support ?

Comment: Sorry, your question seems incoherent to me.   I don't think that calculation of padding elements is unique to Kepler.  Padding must be organized based on the expected access pattern.  I know of no connection between shared memory config and double precision support.  All CUDA GPUs supported by CUDA 7 have double precision support.  [Kepler GPUs have support for 8-byte bank mode](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/index.html#shared-memory-and-warp-shuffle).  Perhaps that is what you are referring to.

Comment: You guys should definitely make it more explicit in the docs. I've read the guides carefully, but I had no idea why I had 32 conflicts in the case like this until I accidentally stumbled on this thread.

Answer (score 11):

Your understanding is false. Bank conflicts happen when threads from the same warp are accessing different values that reside in the same bank.

From CUDA C Programming guide:

> To achieve high bandwidth, shared memory is divided into equally-sized memory modules, called banks, which can be accessed simultaneously. Any memory read or write request made of n addresses that fall in n distinct memory banks can therefore be serviced simultaneously, yielding an overall bandwidth that is n times as high as the bandwidth of a single module.
>
> However, if two addresses of a memory request fall in the same memory bank, there is a bank conflict and the access has to be serialized. The hardware splits a memory request with bank conflicts into as many separate conflict-free requests as necessary, decreasing throughput by a factor equal to the number of separate memory requests. If the number of separate memory requests is n, the initial memory request is said to cause n-way bank conflicts.

Padding is used to avoid bank conflicts. When you know your shared memory access pattern you can determine how to pad your share memory array to avoid bank conflicts.

For example if let's say you have `__shared__ float x[32][32];` and each thread with thread index tid is accessing x like this `somevariable = x[tid][0];`. This will cause 32-way bank conflict because all the threads are accessing different values from the same bank.
To avoid conflicts you pad the array in the first dimension with one more element: `__shared__ float x[32][33];`. That will completely eliminate bank conflicts because now each row will have an bank location that is offset by one against the previous row.

Comment: Thank you +1 as well, I accepted Robert answer because of the examples.