# how to use the array in cudaPitchedPtr type data

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have encountered a problem when trying to use the array within the data type cudaPitchedptr.
I transferred the data from the main function to the global function and print the value. As I set the value to be 12 in the cudaMemset3D, however, the result printed is 0.0000. Attached is my code. I really appreciate it if someone can help me.

```
 #include "cuda_runtime.h"
 #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
 #include "cuPrintf.cu"
 #include "stdio.h" 
 __global__ void printtest(double devptr[])
{

printf("%f\n",devptr[1]);
}




int main()
{

int width=191, height=192, depth=192;
cudaExtent extent= make_cudaExtent( width*sizeof(double),height,depth);
cudaPitchedPtr Ex;
cudaMalloc3D(&Ex,extent);

cudaMemset3D(Ex,12 ,extent);

printtest<<<1,1>>>( (double*) Ex.ptr);
}
```

Comment: You have set the value to 1.22416778342e-250, so the result that is being printed out is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [cudaMemset3D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g35171e821992f71d3c50f17032e079dc) is used to set every *byte* in a range to a value.  Note in the description:

> value- Value to set for each byte of specified memory

So you are setting every byte in your allocated region to 12 (decimal).  Then you're taking 8 of those bytes in a row and attempting to interpet it as a double-precision floating point type.  You're going to get results that aren't what you expect.

If you want to see something sensible, then after your `cudaMalloc3D`, instead of the `cudaMemset3D`, insert this code:

```
  double myval = 1.3579f;  //or whatever value you want to see
  double *hostdata;
  hostdata = (double *)malloc(width*sizeof(double)* height*depth);
  if (hostdata == 0) {printf("malloc fail"); return 1;}
  hostdata[1] = myval;
  cudaMemcpy3DParms p = {0};
  p.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(hostdata, width*sizeof(double), width, height);
  p.dstPtr = Ex;
  p.extent = extent;
  p.srcPos = make_cudaPos(0,0,0);
  p.dstPos = make_cudaPos(0,0,0);
  p.kind=cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
  cudaMemcpy3D(&p);
```

I'd also recommend using [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) after every api call and kernel launch in your code.

You may also be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119943/how-and-when-should-i-use-pitched-pointer-with-the-cuda-api) question/answer.