# Copy the contents of a 3D cudaArray obtained from an OpenGL texture

Tags: cuda, textures, interop

I would like to copy the contents of a **3D** `cudaArray` originating from an OpenGL texture to a "classical" array and vice-versa.

> Note:
> ***In the following snippets, errors checks are omitted for clarity.***

The `cudaArray` is "allocated" this way:

```cpp
cudaArray* texture_array {nullptr};
cudaGraphicsResource* resource{nullptr};

cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&resource, texture.id, GL_TEXTURE_3D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone);
cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &resource, cuda_stream);
cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&texture_array, resource, array_index, mipmap);
```

This operation is successful as I am able to obtain relevant information using
`cudaArrayGetInfo(&description, &extent, &flags, texture_array)` and obtain things like the following example here with a `512 x 512 x 122` texture in format `uint16`.

```cpp
//C-style pseudo-code

description
{
    .x = 16,
    .y = 0,
    .z = 0,
    .w = 0,
    .f = cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned,
};

extent
{
    .width  = 512,
    .height = 512,
    .depth  = 122
};

flags = 0;
```

### First try: linear array

After reading [this answer to a post asking about pitched memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119944) my first try was to use `cudaMemcpy3D` and simulate a pitched array with `pitch` being the row length in bytes like this:

```cpp
std::uint8_t* linear_array{nullptr};

const cudaExtent extent =
{
    .width  = texture.width  * texture.pixel_format_byte_size,
    .height = texture.height,
    .depth  = texture.depth
};
cudaMalloc(&linear_array, extent.width * extent.height * extent.depth);
```

And then copy to it like that:

```
const cudaMemcpy3DParms copy_info =
{
    .srcArray = texture_array,
    .srcPos   =
    {
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .z = 0
    },
    .srcPtr =
    {
        .ptr   = nullptr,
        .pitch = 0, 
        .xsize = 0,
        .ysize = 0
    },

    .dstArray = nullptr,
    .dstPos   =
    {
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .z = 0
    },
    .dstPtr = 
    {
        .ptr   = linear_array,
        .pitch = extent.width, 
        .xsize = texture.width,
        .ysize = texture.height,
    }, 

    .extent = extent,
    .kind   = cudaMemcpyDefault,
};

cudaMemcpy3D(&copy_info)
```

The code above however produces a `cudaErrorInvalidValue` upon call to `cudaMemcpy3D`.
Needless to say, the same thing happens if I reverse the two (source becomes destination and vice-versa).

### Second try: pitched array

*A bit more complicated for me as I intend to modify the data in a `__global__` function, but whatever.*

Similarly, I allocate a (real) pitched array like this:

```cpp
cudaPitchedPtr ptr;
const cudaExtent extent =
{
    .width  = texture.width * texture.pixel_format_byte_size,
    .height = texture.height,
    .depth  = texture.depth,
};

cudaMalloc3D(&ptr, extent);
```

And copy to it like this:

```cpp
const cudaMemcpy3DParms copy_info =
{
    .srcArray = texture_array,
    .srcPos   =
    {
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .z = 0
    },
    .srcPtr =
    {
        .ptr   = nullptr,
        .pitch = 0,
        .xsize = 0,
        .ysize = 0
    },

    .dstArray = nullptr,
    .dstPos   =
    {
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .z = 0
    },
    .dstPtr = ptr,

    .extent = extent,
    .kind = cudaMemcpyDefault
};

cudaMemcpy3D(&copy_info);
```

But I also got `cudaErrorInvalidValue` upon call to `cudaMemcpy3D`.

---

What am I doing wrong?
Is a limitation of the API forbidding me to call `cudaMemcpy3D` when the array is a texture from a graphics API? If so, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various tests (copying to another `cudaArray` and other similar things), it appears the problem came from a misunderstanding.

The documentation clearly states:

> " If a CUDA array is participating in the copy, the extent is defined in terms of that array's elements".

Thus, `copy_info.extent` has to be (in my context) the extent retrieved by `cudaArrayGetInfo`.

Comment: I was just about to post a slightly kurter version of the same information as an answer, but you saved me the trouble. Thanks for answering your own question. `cudaMemcy3D` is a minefield of an API, and it's really easy to get arguments wrong in complex copy situations like your use case.